# Overlapping AxesLabel in ListPointPlot3D

Tags: plotting

My input code:

data:

```
plotting1m1 = {{3, 1, 0}, {4, 1, 11/36}, {5, 1, 0}, {6, 1, 0}, {7, 1, 0}, {8, 1, 0}, {9, 1, 25/36}, {10, 1, 0}, {11, 1, 0}, {12, 1, 0}, {13, 1, 0}, {14, 1, 0}}; 
plotting1m2 = {{3, 2, 0}, {4, 2, 7/18}, {5, 2, 0}, {6, 2, 0}, {7, 2, 0}, {8, 2, 0}, {9, 2, 11/18}, {10, 2, 0}, {11, 2, 0}, {12, 2, 0}, {13, 2, 0}, {14, 2, 0}}; 
plotting1m3 = {{3, 3, 0}, {4, 3, 2/9}, {5, 3, 2/9}, {6, 3, 0}, {7, 3, 0}, {8, 3, 0}, {9, 3, 4/9}, {10, 3, 0}, {11, 3, 1/9}, {12, 3, 0}, {13, 3, 0}, {14, 3, 0}}; 
plotting2m1 = {{3, 1, 0}, {4, 1, 3/25}, {5, 1, 0}, {6, 1, 0}, {7, 1, 0}, {8, 1, 0}, {9, 1, 43/50}, {10, 1, 1/50}, {11, 1, 0}, {12, 1, 0}, {13, 1, 0}, {14, 1, 0}}; 
plotting2m2 = {{3, 2, 3/50}, {4, 2, 1/10}, {5, 2, 0}, {6, 2, 0}, {7, 2, 0}, {8, 2, 0}, {9, 2, 21/25}, {10, 2, 0}, {11, 2, 0}, {12, 2, 0}, {13, 2, 0}, {14, 2, 0}}; 
plotting2m3 = {{3, 3, 23/50}, {4, 3, 2/25}, {5, 3, 1/25}, {6, 3, 0}, {7, 3, 1/10}, {8, 3, 0}, {9, 3, 1/25}, {10, 3, 2/25}, {11, 3, 1/25}, {12, 3, 0}, {13, 3, 2/25}, {14, 3, 2/25}}; 
plotting3m1 = {{3, 1, 0}, {4, 1, 0}, {5, 1, 0}, {6, 1, 0}, {7, 1, 0}, {8, 1, 0}, {9, 1, 1}, {10, 1, 0}, {11, 1, 0}, {12, 1, 0}, {13, 1, 0}, {14, 1, 0}}; 
plotting3m2 = {{3, 2, 0}, {4, 2, 0}, {5, 2, 0}, {6, 2, 0}, {7, 2, 0}, {8, 2, 0}, {9, 2, 1}, {10, 2, 0}, {11, 2, 0}, {12, 2, 0}, {13, 2, 0}, {14, 2, 0}}; 
plotting3m3 = {{3, 3, 0}, {4, 3, 0}, {5, 3, 0}, {6, 3, 0}, {7, 3, 0}, {8, 3, 0}, {9, 3, 1}, {10, 3, 0}, {11, 3, 0}, {12, 3, 0}, {13, 3, 0}, {14, 3, 0}};
```

plotting:

```
method1 = {plotting1m1, plotting1m2, plotting1m3};
method2 = {plotting2m1, plotting2m2, plotting2m3};
method3 = {plotting3m1, plotting3m2, plotting3m3};
case = Table[node, {node, 3, 14, 1}];
ticks = {case, {{1, "m1"}, {2, "m2"}, {3, "m3"}}, Range[0, 1, 0.1]};
plotstyle = {RGBColor[0, 0, 1], RGBColor[0, 0.5, 0], 
   RGBColor[0.5, 0, 0.5]};
axeslabels = {"Number", "Obj", "S"};
ticksstyle = 
  Directive[Black, FontSize -> 18, FontFamily -> "Times New Roman"];
plotLegends = 
  SwatchLegend[plotstyle, {"m1", "m2", "m3 "}, 
   LegendLabel -> "Used Methods", 
   LegendFunction -> (Framed[#, Background -> LightBlue] &)];
Show[
 {
  ListPointPlot3D[
   {
    Style[Flatten[method1, 1], 
     Directive[RGBColor[0, 0, 1], PointSize[0.012]]],
    Style[Flatten[method2, 1], 
     Directive[RGBColor[0, 0.5, 0], PointSize[0.012]]],
    Style[Flatten[method3, 1], 
     Directive[RGBColor[0.5, 0, 0.5], PointSize[0.012]]]
    },
   PlotRange -> All,
   Ticks -> ticks,
   TicksStyle -> ticksstyle,
   AxesLabel -> axeslabels,
   AxesStyle -> Directive[Black],
   LabelStyle -> 
    Directive[ FontSize -> 18, FontFamily -> "Times New Roman"],
   PlotLegends -> plotLegends
   ],
  Graphics3D[
   {Style[Line@method1, RGBColor[0, 0, 1]], 
    Style[Line@method2, RGBColor[0, 0.5, 0]], 
    Style[Line@method3, RGBColor[0.5, 0, 0.5]]}
   ]
  },
 ImageSize -> 1200]
```

I'm wondering how can I get (now it's handmade):
[image: desirable plot with overlapping axis]

i.e. overlapping X-Axis ("Number") for each {m1,m2,m3} in Y-Axis ("Obj").

**1. Is there any way to overlap AxesLabel like that?**

**2. If you find something which can be improved in my code I'll be very thankful also.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

$Version

(* "12.3.1 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (June 19, 2021)" *)
```

Use indexed variables to simplify code

```
plotting[1][
   1] = {{3, 1, 0}, {4, 1, 11/36}, {5, 1, 0}, {6, 1, 0}, {7, 1, 0}, {8, 1, 
    0}, {9, 1, 25/36}, {10, 1, 0}, {11, 1, 0}, {12, 1, 0}, {13, 1, 0}, {14, 1,
     0}};
plotting[1][
   2] = {{3, 2, 0}, {4, 2, 7/18}, {5, 2, 0}, {6, 2, 0}, {7, 2, 0}, {8, 2, 
    0}, {9, 2, 11/18}, {10, 2, 0}, {11, 2, 0}, {12, 2, 0}, {13, 2, 0}, {14, 2,
     0}};
plotting[1][
   3] = {{3, 3, 0}, {4, 3, 2/9}, {5, 3, 2/9}, {6, 3, 0}, {7, 3, 0}, {8, 3, 
    0}, {9, 3, 4/9}, {10, 3, 0}, {11, 3, 1/9}, {12, 3, 0}, {13, 3, 0}, {14, 3,
     0}};
plotting[2][
   1] = {{3, 1, 0}, {4, 1, 3/25}, {5, 1, 0}, {6, 1, 0}, {7, 1, 0}, {8, 1, 
    0}, {9, 1, 43/50}, {10, 1, 1/50}, {11, 1, 0}, {12, 1, 0}, {13, 1, 0}, {14,
     1, 0}};
plotting[2][
   2] = {{3, 2, 3/50}, {4, 2, 1/10}, {5, 2, 0}, {6, 2, 0}, {7, 2, 0}, {8, 2, 
    0}, {9, 2, 21/25}, {10, 2, 0}, {11, 2, 0}, {12, 2, 0}, {13, 2, 0}, {14, 2,
     0}};
plotting[2][
   3] = {{3, 3, 23/50}, {4, 3, 2/25}, {5, 3, 1/25}, {6, 3, 0}, {7, 3, 
    1/10}, {8, 3, 0}, {9, 3, 1/25}, {10, 3, 2/25}, {11, 3, 1/25}, {12, 3, 
    0}, {13, 3, 2/25}, {14, 3, 2/25}};
plotting[3][
   1] = {{3, 1, 0}, {4, 1, 0}, {5, 1, 0}, {6, 1, 0}, {7, 1, 0}, {8, 1, 0}, {9,
     1, 1}, {10, 1, 0}, {11, 1, 0}, {12, 1, 0}, {13, 1, 0}, {14, 1, 0}};
plotting[3][
   2] = {{3, 2, 0}, {4, 2, 0}, {5, 2, 0}, {6, 2, 0}, {7, 2, 0}, {8, 2, 0}, {9,
     2, 1}, {10, 2, 0}, {11, 2, 0}, {12, 2, 0}, {13, 2, 0}, {14, 2, 0}};
plotting[3][
   3] = {{3, 3, 0}, {4, 3, 0}, {5, 3, 0}, {6, 3, 0}, {7, 3, 0}, {8, 3, 0}, {9,
     3, 1}, {10, 3, 0}, {11, 3, 0}, {12, 3, 0}, {13, 3, 0}, {14, 3, 0}};
```

Simplifications using the indexed variables:

```
Table[method[n] = plotting[n] /@ Range[3], {n, 1, 3}];

case = Range[3, 14];

Format[m[n_]] := Subscript[m, n]

ticks = {case, {#, m[#]} & /@ Range[3], Range[0, 1, 0.1]};

plotstyle = {Blue, RGBColor[0, 0.5, 0], Purple};

axeslabels = {"Number", "Obj", "S"};

ticksstyle = 
  Directive[Black, FontSize -> 18, FontFamily -> "Times New Roman"];

plotLegends =
  SwatchLegend[plotstyle, m /@ Range[3],
   LegendLabel -> "Used Methods",
   LegendFunction ->
    (Framed[#, Background -> Opacity[0.2, LightBlue]] &)];
```

Plotting:

```
Show[
 ListPointPlot3D[
  Style[Flatten[method[#], 1], Directive[plotstyle[[#]],
      PointSize[0.012]]] & /@ Range[3],
  PlotRange -> All,
  Ticks -> ticks,
  TicksStyle -> ticksstyle,
  AxesLabel -> axeslabels,
  AxesStyle -> Black,
  LabelStyle -> ticksstyle,
  PlotLegends -> plotLegends],
 Graphics3D[
  {Line[{{case[[1]], 2, 0}, {case[[-1]], 2, 0}}],
   Style[Line@method[#], plotstyle[[#]]] & /@ Range[3],
   Table[
    Text[Style[#, ticksstyle], {#, n - 0.1, -0.05}] & /@ case, 
      {n, 2, 3}]}],
 ImageSize -> 1200,
 AxesEdge -> {{-1, -1}, {1, -1}, {-1, -1}}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

you can use the magical `ListLinePlot3D`

```
   ListLinePlot3D[{plotting1m1, plotting1m2, plotting1m3, plotting2m1, 
  plotting2m2, plotting2m3, plotting3m1, plotting3m2, plotting3m3}, 
 PlotRange -> All, PlotMarkers -> Automatic, PlotTheme -> "Detailed"
 , PlotStyle -> {Directive[RGBColor[0, 0, 1], Thin], 
   Directive[RGBColor[0, 0, 1], Thin], 
   Directive[RGBColor[0, 0, 1], Thin], 
   Directive[RGBColor[0, 0.5, 0], Thin], 
   Directive[RGBColor[0, 0.5, 0], Thin], 
   Directive[RGBColor[0, 0.5, 0], Thin], 
   Directive[RGBColor[0.5, 0, 0.5], Thin], 
   Directive[RGBColor[0.5, 0, 0.5], Thin], 
   Directive[RGBColor[0.5, 0, 0.5], Thin]}, 
 Ticks -> {Table[i, {i, 3, 14}], {{1, "m1"}, {2, "m2"}, {3, "m3"}}, 
   Table[i, {i, 0, 1, 0.2}]}, 
 PlotLegends -> 
  SwatchLegend[{RGBColor[0, 0, 1], RGBColor[0, 0.5, 0], 
    RGBColor[0.5, 0, 0.5]}, {"m1", "m2", "m3 "}, 
   LegendLabel -> "Used Methods", 
   LegendFunction -> (Framed[#, Background -> LightBlue] &)], 
 AxesLabel -> axeslabels]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! But ListLinePlot3D is accessible only with 12.3 version+. I forgot to tell version I'm working :) It's 11.3

Comment: @vladpopovcev u r welcome!